# Program exited with code 0320?

Tags: c

[C code]
We are runing a program and gives this error:
**program exited with code 0320**
Anyone know what this code means?
thanks for your answers!

Comment: It means the author of the code returned 0320 for whatever reason on-exit. Is there a *name* for this phantom program?

Answer (score 1):

`0320` is likely the octal representation of decimal `208`, though I'm not sure why the status would be reported in octal.

It means that the program terminated by executing either

```
exit(208);
```

or

```
return 208;
```

from the `main` function.

Either that, or the program was compiled in C89/C90 mode, and its execution reached the closing `}` of `main` without executing a `return` statement or `exit` call, and the status value is garbage (possibly the value of the last expression evaluated, or a value that happened to be left lying in some particular CPU register)

Depending on the operating system, there is not necessarily any general convention for what exit codes mean. In Unix-like systems, 0 denotes success, and 1 denotes some generic failure.

The meaning, if any, depends entirely on the program itself.

It would help to know what operating system you're using, and what produced the message "program exited with code 0320" (a shell normally would not produce that message).